# Android studio preview with Java 1.7 support is broken for me

Tags: android-studio, java-7, android-4.4-kitkat

This is what I do (Android studio 0.3.2):

1. New project
2. Everything API 19 (min, target, compile)
3. Enable Java 1.7 support
4. Activity with navigation drawer (Something complex to just try)
5. Build the project

When I go to any layout, I get this:

[image: android studio error]

Technically I have everything working with Java 1.7. Project settings says 1.7, my "java -v" says 1.7, everywhere I see it.

Android SDK:

[image: Android SDK]

Comment: Do you use java 7 sdk in Project Settings -> Android SDK -> JDK Location and in File -> Other Settings -> Default Project Setup did you declare a Java 7 SDK and set it for all Android SDKs?

Comment: I don't see any "Android SDK" in Project Settings. I see in in project structure. I will update the post with what I have there.

Comment: Sorry yes Project Structure

Comment: Same problem here. But in fact preview is working ok. Just this annoying false warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed since 0.3.2. The relevant bug is https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61669